# Why does my ServiceStack service throw an exception?

Tags: c#, web-services, servicestack

I have constructed a simple Rest service using [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net) (which is brilliant), that returns a list of key value pairs.

My service looks like this:

```
 public class ServiceListAll : RestServiceBase<ListAllResponse>
{
    public override object OnGet(ListAllResponse request)
    {          
        APIClient c = VenueServiceHelper.CheckAndGetClient(request.APIKey, VenueServiceHelper.Methods.ListDestinations);

        if (c == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            if ((RequestContext.AbsoluteUri.Contains("counties")))
            {
                return General.GetListOfCounties();
            }

            else if ((RequestContext.AbsoluteUri.Contains("destinations")))
            {
                return General.GetListOfDestinations();
            }

            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my response looks like this:

```
    public class ListAllResponse
{
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; }
    public string APIKey { get; set; }     
}
```

and I have mapped the rest URL as follows:

```
.Add<ListAllResponse>("/destinations")
.Add<ListAllResponse>("/counties")
```

when calling the service

> http://localhost:5000/counties/?apikey=xxx&format=xml

I receive this exception (a breakpoint in the first line of the service is not hit):

> NullReferenceException
>   
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   
>   
>   at ServiceStack.Text.XmlSerializer.SerializeToStream(Object obj, Stream stream) at ServiceStack.Common.Web.HttpResponseFilter.<GetStreamSerializer>b_*3(IRequestContext r, Object o, Stream s) at ServiceStack.Common.Web.HttpResponseFilter.<>c*_DisplayClass1.<GetResponseSerializer>b__0(IRequestContext httpReq, Object dto, IHttpResponse httpRes) at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Extensions.HttpResponseExtensions.WriteToResponse(IHttpResponse response, Object result, ResponseSerializerDelegate defaultAction, IRequestContext serializerCtx, Byte[] bodyPrefix, Byte[] bodySuffix)

The exception is thrown regardless of whether I include any parameters in call or not. I have also created a number of other services along the same lines in the same project which work fine. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what this means?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your web service design is a little backwards, Your **Request DTO** should go on `RestServiceBase<TRequest>` not your response. And if you're creating a REST-ful service I recommend the name (i.e. Request DTO) of your service to be a noun, e.g. in this case maybe Codes.

Also I recommend having and using the same strong-typed Response for your service with the name following the convention of '{RequestDto}Response', e.g. CodesResponse.

Finally return an empty response instead of null so clients need only handle an empty result set not a null response.

Here's how I would re-write your service:

```
 [RestService("/codes/{Type}")]
 public class Codes {
      public string APIKey { get; set; }     
      public string Type { get; set; }
 }

 public class CodesResponse {
      public CodesResponse() {
           Results = new List<string>();
      }

      public List<string> Results { get; set; }
 }

 public class CodesService : RestServiceBase<Codes>
 {
      public override object OnGet(Codes request)
      {          
           APIClient c = VenueServiceHelper.CheckAndGetClient(request.APIKey, 
              VenueServiceHelper.Methods.ListDestinations);

           var response = new CodesResponse();
           if (c == null) return response;

           if (request.Type == "counties") 
                response.Results = General.GetListOfCounties();
           else if (request.Type == "destinations") 
                response.Results = General.GetListOfDestinations();

           return response; 
     }
 }
```

You can either use the [RestService] attribute or the following route (which does the same thing):

```
Routes.Add<Codes>("/codes/{Type}");
```

Which will allow you to call the service like so:

```
http://localhost:5000/codes/counties?apikey=xxx&format=xml
```

Comment: That's great, many thanks, I really appreciate the effort. I actually rewrote the service myself in the meantime and I'm pleased to say that I did it broadly along the lines you suggested and it now works successfully. I also included ResponseStatus in my response as per your answer to http://stackoverflow.com/q/4692313/20048